# StoreKit show me Invalid product id

Tags: iphone, storekit

I used In App Purchase and i follow all step to create In App purchase but my program always show me invalid product id.By In App Purchase status in itunes is "Waiting for review".
What should i do so that i get my product id valid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get this working even if 'Waiting in review'.  As a matter of interest were you using this guide?:  http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

I had this error when making a silly mistake with setting kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId.  The poster called Yasir had the error once he had rejected binary so have a read of the comments in that article.